# Number of polynomials with distinct roots.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots

Let $K$ be a finite field with $q \ge 3$ elements. Denote by $M$ the set of all polynomials of degree $q-2$ in $K[X]$ with all coefficients distinct and nonzero. Find the number of polynomials in $M$ with $q-2$ distinct roots.
The proof I have seen goes like this:

We obviously only need to calculate the polynomials that satisfy the property with $f(0)=1$ and then multiply the number at the end with $q-1$. For polynomials of the form $f(X)=a_{q-2}X^{q-2}+a_{q-1}X^{q-1}+...+a_1X+1$ consider the matrices:

$A=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_{q-3} & a_{q-2}\\
a_{q-2} & 1 & a_1 & \dots & a_{q-4} & a_{q-3}\\
a_{q-3} & a_{q-2}& 1 & \dots & a_{q-5} & a_{q-4}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \dots & 1 & a_1\\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \dots & a_{q-2} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$B=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1\\
y & x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_{q-3} & x_{q-2}\\
y^2 & {x_1}^2 & {x_2}^2 & \dots & {x_{q-3}}^2 & {x_{q-2}}^2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
y^{q-3} & {x_1}^{q-3} & {x_2}^{q-3} & \dots & {x_{q-3}}^{q-3} & {x_{q-2}}^{q-3}\\
y^{q-2} & {x_1}^{q-2} & {x_2}^{q-2} & \dots & {x_{q-3}}^{q-2} & {x_{q-2}}^{q-2}
\end{pmatrix}$

where $x_i$ are the distinct nonzero roots of $f$ and $y$ is the other element of $K^*$

We find out that

$AB=
\begin{pmatrix}
f(y) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
yf(y) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
{y}^{2}f(y) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots&  & \vdots & \vdots\\
{y}^{q-3}f(y) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
{y}^{q-2}f(y) & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. This matrix has rank $1$ and $B$ is invertible as its determinant is a Vandermonde determinant, so nonzero. This implies that $rank(A)=1$. So all minors of order $2$ are zero.

So
$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2\\
1 & a_1
\end{vmatrix}$
$=$
$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_3\\
1 & a_2
\end{vmatrix}$
$=$ $\dots$ $=$
$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_{q-2}\\
1 & a_{q-3}
\end{vmatrix}$
$=0$ and thus we find out that $a_i={a_1}^i$ for all

$i \in$ {$2, 3, \dots, q-2$}. Therefore $a_1$ is a generator of $K^*$ and it follows that all polynomials are of the form $f(X)=1+aX+a^2X^2+ \dots + a^{q-2}X^{q-2}$ where $a$ is a generator of $K^*$. Conversely, we find out that all polynomials of this form satisfy the condition. So these are the only ones. Since $K^*$ has $\phi(q-1)$ generators, the number of polynomials that satisfy the condition is $(q-1) \phi(q-1)$.

I understand the solution, but I want to know where the idea to consider the matrices $A$ and $B$ comes from. Is it a method commonly used? Are there other instances where linear algebra is used in abstract algebra (especially in polynomial problems)?

Comment: At which step did you encounter a difficulty? We can only give a useful answer if you tell us more details like these. Otherwise we would just be repeating the standard solution which you possibly have already consulted, and probably doesn't address your actual confusion.

Comment: @Trebor I have added an edit explaining my concerns with the problem.

Comment: I see, my close vote is now retracted.